# Color page inside of the set height and width

Tags: color, margins

I am trying to make a colored page in LaTeX. But so far, what I have tried colors the entire page. Which I think does not look that good.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

\newpage

\pagecolor{SkyBlue}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

To be able to set the height and width of the colored box would be great. 
I also have no idea how to make it fit inside of the standard margins.

[image: Example of pageoutput]

Comment: `\pagecolor` sets the page background color. You probably want to look at the **mdframed** package.

Comment: I updated the post to clearify what I am looking for =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can be done with a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx,xhfill}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X !{\color{white}\vrule width 2pt} X }
\rowcolor{SkyBlue}
\multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{SkyBlue}}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
  \leavevmode\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{6ex}\Large\xrfill{2pt}[white]\sffamily\ 
  Review
  \xrfill{2pt}[white]}\\
%
\rowcolor{SkyBlue}
\lipsum[1] 
&
\lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what exactly you want. You can use `\rule` together with `\textcolor` to get a colored rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\textcolor{green}{\rule{10cm}{9cm}}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you want some colored block drawn in the background you can do this using TikZ, when you use the options `remember picture,overlay` in the page header, or direct after `\newpage`. If you want to draw the colored box to the text area margins use my recent `tikzpagenodes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\newcoloredpage}[1]{%
    \newpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
        \fill [#1] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \vspace{-2.5\baselineskip}%
    \par
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\newcoloredpage{blue}
\section*{Review}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you want to color the background of a paragraph you could use `adjustbox` with the `minipage` and `bgcolor` keys (and maybe `margin` to add some more margin):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,bgcolor=blue}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

However, such a paragraph can't be broken across the page. If you need this the `framed` or better the more modern `mdframed` package would be the way to go.
<sub>I'm working on a TikZ-based decoration package which would be usable here as well, but isn't finished yet.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in ConTeXt, you can use `\setupbackgrounds` to color the page.

```
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color, backgroundcolor=blue:2]
```

will color the whole page blue.

```
\setupbackgrounds[text][...]
```

will color the text area (what you want). One can also use

```
\setupbackgrounds[text][leftmargin][....]
```

to color the left margin of the text area and so on.

Instead of `background=color`, one can choose `background=...` an overlay and then use metapost to draw the background.